# How Can I share a dynamic report using tableau

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have a redshift database and it has an insane quantity of information, right now I'm using tableau to develop my reports but its a headache when I try to share the report with other users , I like to share dynamic reports with no tableau users there's any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share an interactive Tableau report you can do this using Tableau Public - obviously this is public so should not be used for sensitive content. If you want to share private reporting then the only way to do this and retain interactivity is by using Tableau Server or Tableau Online.

Comment: thanks but I have sensitive info so I can't use tableau public, and tableau reader only works for extract and I have a live cxn

Comment: Can't you publish your data source to Tableau Online and have it refresh there?

Comment: Could be but we need a faster choice, tableau online gets slow when you have some users playing with the same report